# Confuse with this time format in Android AlarmManager

Tags: android-alarms

I am very confuse with these time format :

```
 alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), alarmIntent);
```

or

```
alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60*1000, alarmIntent);
```

What is `60*1000` and `(10 * 1000), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`. Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the official documentation of AlarmManager API (found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)), these numbers are used to define the time at which the alarm should be set off. So the numbers (10*1000) represent the time in milliseconds (or simply 10 secs) added to the current time of the system (again in milliseconds). So, the alarm in this case will be set off at 10 secs after the command is issued (current system time + 10 secs).

The second parameter (24*60*60*1000) represents a time of 1 day (24 hours, 60 mins, 60 secs, and 1000 milliseconds in every sec). Since the complete expression is not specified, I can't tell the exact significance of this parameter.

In the second expression also, 60*1000 represents 1 min (60 * 1000 = 60000 milliseconds = 1 min)

Feel free to post any doubts that you still have about the meaning of these numbers.

Comment: i have edit the question and put complete line of code. So  `System.currentTimeMillis() + (10 * 1000), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)` will be firing in the next 10 seconds and another 10 seconds again after the 1st alarm?

Comment: No, the second parameter is the duration after which the alarm repeats itself. So, in this case, the alarm will be fired for the first time after 10 seconds and it will repeat itself every day (fired after every 24*60*60*1000 milliseconds i.e. 1 day).

Comment: Also, if this answers your question, dont forget to accept it as the answer. It will help others with the same problem to easily find the answer.

Comment: i will mark it when u answer this question :) . What is the best method to set an alarm in which will run according to time that receive from internet. Let say, I set the alarm to run at 14:50 (2:50PM) today, current time is 12:00 PM. Should I set it using `calendar.add` or using time elapsed ?

Comment: Well, that's unfair! You should mark it answered if the question you posted has been answered! And further to your commented question, if you use calendar.add, it does not return any value so the alarm will actually not receive any time from this. You should use System time elapsed which returns a long value (milliseconds)/